# Windows Defender, "Potentially unwanted app found" gfdriver.sys

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, unwanted-application

Windows Defender scan "Potentially unwanted app found" `gfdriver.sys`

I look in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\` and the file is nowhere to be found... Their description of this file is also empty except for calling it "App:NetFilterSDK"

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=App:NetFilterSDK&ThreatID=268964

Anyone have any idea what this file may be or is this a bug in Defender?

Windows 10
Version 2004
Build 19041.329

All latest updates installed and even just ran DISM + sfc /scannow and it repaired corrupt files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Defender quarnatined gfdriver.sys, what is it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1625252/windows-defender-quarnatined-gfdriver-sys-what-is-it)

Answer (score 4):

Look in your Windows Defender Quarantine (Threats). It is probably there, and if so, then properly removed. It will go away after a few days so it may already be gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely tied to a Software Development Kit, hence "SDK." You can quarantine or delete it and start opening programs you know of that have SDK's attached to them to see if they work or if it re-installs the package.