# Windows Defender quarnatined gfdriver.sys, what is it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

Windows Defender found this file in my system32\drivers directory: gfdriver.sys.  Anyone have any idea what this file may be?

I'm normally very careful where I browse and what I download, so I'm curious how I might have got it.  Where does it come from and what can I do to not download this again?

Thanks for any help, Google didn't really find any solid information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see this on any of my Windows 10 machines, and to the best of my knowledge, it is appropriate for Windows Defender to quarantine it.

You can remove from Quarantine or it will disappear on its own in a few days.

[WD Quarantine gfdriver[1](https://superuser.com/questions/1564178/windows-defender-potentially-unwanted-app-found-gfdriver-sys)

I did see this that may help you with where it came from:

Quote from a Microsoft Answers thread:

> I used to have (I think so) a virus called **Quick Driver Updater**
> that I got from a cracked game

Driver Update Apps are all over the place in Ads on websites.

Comment: Thanks.  That Microsoft link is blank for me (it literally says "no technical details are available") but searching for "Quick Driver Updater virus" got me some useful information where to look.  Here's a link from Malware bytes: https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/258955-removal-instructions-for-quick-driver-updater/

Comment: I didn’t post a link because there are so many Driver Updaters. But I am pleased you posted some additional information.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens to me WD says it is tied to one "APP:NetFilterSDK."

This tells us it is from some Software Development Kit and is most likely safe to use. As for where it originated, your guess is as good as mine. It could literally come from almost anywhere as SDK kits are quite common in their packaging with games, apps and wares.

It may be worth noting that I haven't had this flag pop up for quite some time (like years) until I recently re-installed GPU Tweak-III (which causes frequent BSOD crashes and GPU driver issues) AMD Overdrive and EVGA Precision X1. Running at lower clock speeds and/or even removing the software entirely seems to fix the issue.